# Arduino Genuino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno

I have Arduino Genuino Uno and 'Extra PC' Debian Linux USB dongle. I can get board data S/N etc., but TX LED permanently lit and data showing on TX line with an oscilloscope. I get the following error message:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied
```

An error occurred while uploading the sketch.

Any body know how to create this device?

Comment: what is `Extra PC`?

Comment: I think it means `XTRA PC` https://www.xtra-pc.com/ - which are these PC on a dongle thing, for windows XP, Vista, 7 .... not for connecting to a UNO

Comment: access rights https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Linux#toc6

Comment: That is a overpriced and overrated usb flashdrive with linux installed on it. They ask 5 times more than the current prices for fast usb flashdrives. Grab an old usb flashdrive you already have, download the iso of your choice and use Rufus to put it on the flashdrive. Install it on a second fast flashdrive. Or try puppylinux which is loaded into ram for extra speed. All for free if you already have a flashdrive. Even a used ssd drive is cheaper than XtraPC. That will make a 10 year old computer run like a 3 year old computer. M Saunders, can you return it and get your money back?

Comment: Try it with sudo